# Convert Linq query to List without using generic parameter

Tags: linq, generic-collections

If I have an unevaluated query:

```cs
var q = (my linq query);
```

That happens to return a type of `DbSet<T>` and I need it to resolve to a `List<T>` because I'm about to lose the context within which it was created.

Normally I would just say `q.Cast<T>.ToList()` but at this place in the code I don't have `T` so how do I do this?

I do have the `System.Type` of `T` however. I came up with a work around but I am having to load a new `List<T>` (created with reflection) with the results of `q`. I don't like it because it's awkward and I'm loading another list but maybe loading a list is what `ToList()` does anyway.

Is there a better way?

```cs
public static System.Collections.IEnumerable RootCollection(string collectionPropertyName)
{
  using (var db = new Model1())
  {
    var col = GetRootCollection(db, collectionPropertyName);
    System.Type generic = typeof(List<>);
    System.Type constructed = generic.MakeGenericType(col.GetType().GetGenericArguments().First());
    var list = constructed.GetConstructor(new Type[] {col.GetType() }).Invoke(new object[] { col });
    return (System.Collections.IEnumerable)list;
  }
}
```

Comment: Will it let you use something like `q.Cast(Of q.ElementType).ToList()`?

Comment: Thanks. `Of` is vb syntax. I don't think `Cast` will accept an argument of `System.Type`